# Strange Black Bar Appearing HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to create a link section in a HTML document. I have a couple links containing images. The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/u6Tmt/. As you can see after the SO image there is a little black bar which looks almost like an underscore. What is causing this black bar to appear and how do I get rid of it?

In case you don't know what I'm talking about, here is an image to help:

[image]

Also here is another copy of the code:

```
<div id="links">
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1916721/cabellicar123">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" alt="stack overflow">
  </a>

  <a href="https://github.com/cabellicar123">
    <img src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/favicon.ico" alt="github">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just close your first anchor tag on the line above it, and the line should disappear.

Comment: @NicholasV. That also worked, but I thought HTML ignored whitespace like newlines?

Comment: I'm honestly not an expert in these nitpick instances :-/ I was just fiddling around with your jsfiddle and figured that out.

Comment: @NicholasV. I have since created the theory that because the newline is within an anchor tag the whitespace is not ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bar is the default underline of hyperlinks.

Add this rule to your CSS stylesheet to get rid of it

```
DIV#links A { text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: Why does it not show up after the second link? Also why does this occur for non text elements?

Comment: @cabellicar123 because the linke break between the image tag and the closing anchor tag with its indentation is considered a whitespace, which gets displayed.

Comment: @cabellicar123 If you put something (text, another anchor, etc.) after the 2nd anchor, you will see the underline there as well.

Comment: I see. But why then is the stackoverflow flair ok with having the line break?

Comment: @cabellicar123 I should have been more specific, something inline.  text, anchor, span, etc.  http://jsfiddle.net/PKLDV/1/  Spaces are treated in funny ways sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt have thought it an issue but if you change

```
<img src="image URL" alt="stack overflow">
```

to

```
 <img src="image URL" alt="stack overflow"/>
```

and remove all spaces in the

```
<A>
```

your fiddle fixes

Edit: This & cobra_fast's answer

Comment: That fixes the highlighted syntax error in the jsfiddle because jsfiddle assumes xhtml.  It does not however remove the black underline.

Comment: I do believe that in html 5 the `/` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a space in your first a-tag and the hyperlink is underlining it. When you use the a-tags with images, put it on the same line and it seems to work:

```
<div id="links">
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916721/cabellicar123"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" alt="stack overflow"></a>
<a href="https://github.com/cabellicar123"><img src="https://web.archive.org/web/20190109105720/https://assets-cdn.github.com/favicon.ico" alt="github"></a>
</div>
```

[image: stack overflow]
[image: github]